# Finding Dataset "edges" in SQL

Tags: sql, database, vertica

I have an enormous set of data that was loaded into a SQL database incorrectly (it's a Vertica DB, if that matters).

Each row has an id and a timestamp. The data was loaded sequentially (sequential ids), however the timestamps were converted incorrectly, resulting in all times being loaded as "AM".

Here's a simplified example of what's in the DB:

```
id    |      time
001   | 2013-01-01 00:00:01 // Jan 1st
002   | 2013-01-01 01:20:00
...   | ...
500   | 2013-01-01 11:59:59
501   | 2013-01-01 00:00:01 // should be 12:00:01 (PM)
502   | 2013-01-01 00:10:00 // should be 12:10:00 (PM)
...   | ...
750   | 2013-01-01 11:59:59 // should be 23:59:59 (PM)
751   | 2013-01-02 00:00:00 // next day (the 2nd)
```

I need a query that will find me ID ranges for rows that need 12 hours added to their time. For example, for the example data above, the row returned should be `501, 750`. This way I could add 12 hours where the id >= 501, and <= 750.

Basically, I need some sort of a look-back + look-forward mechanism. Programmatically, it would mean iterating over each row and checking whether the *day* of the date is the same as the next row, and checking whether the *time* is earlier than the previous row. However, I'm sure there's some better way to do it in SQL...

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Need to know function names to extract `date` and `time` from your (apparent) `datetime` column.

Comment: It's Vertica, but I just need some SQL pseudocode for the logic. I can handle the specifics of my RDBMS in implementation. Now that I think about it, it's two joins on itsself, perhaps? One with where b.id = a.id - 1, and another where b.id = a.id + 1? Hmmm...

Comment: I was thinking of a single `SELF JOIN`.

Comment: "look-back" and "look-forward" in standard SQL is done with window functions. `lag()` and `lead()`. Don't know if Vertica supports that.

Comment: Aha, lag() and lead()! Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name... I'll try fiddling with those.

Comment: I've got some pseudocode that may work... I'll start playing around with this: `select max(id), min(id) from
  (SELECT id, time
   FROM blah
   WHERE
     (diff(lag(time) - time) > 10 hours OR dayOf(time) != dayOf(lead(time)))
     AND serverId = 'blah'
   ORDER BY id ASC;
) group by day;`

Answer (score 0):

This is **not exactly** what you're looking for, but it will give all row pairs that are out of sync for their given day.

```
SELECT t1.id As 'ID1', t1.timestamp As 'Stamp1', t2.id As 'ID2', t2.timestamp As 'Stamp2' 
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table1 t2 ON Date(t1.timestamp) = Date(t2.timestamp) AND 
                  Time(t2.timestamp) <= Time(t1.timestamp) AND
                  t1.id <= t2.id
WHERE t1.id <> t2.id OR Time(t2.timestamp) <> Time(t1.timestamp)
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Here's [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d9d39/8)